# How to Write Network Protocol Handlers

Tags: python, networking, tcp, protocols, handlers

I'm trying to write my own protocol so that multiple servers can pass data and connect with each other, kind of like mongo://. I have been looking at TCP & I understand ports, but how do I write something so that people can just do something like connect("proto://example.com:6767/") ?

Also, I'm writing in python.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out the [twisted framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)? It kicks ass and *may* help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to look into [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and writing a subclass of [`BaseHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#basehandler-objects), specifically the functions `protocol_request` and `protocol_response`.

Whether the way urllib2 handles request/response cycles suits your application is up to you to decide -- it may or may not be exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at Twisted and it seems like it could fit for me, but how do I connect to the server? I know I can't curl because it says unsupported protocol...

Comment: To connect to your server the application/environment *from* where you connect must know how to handle your protocol. So if you are using Python, all parties must have access to your custom `BaseHandler` so that they can use the appropriate protocol. With twisted I don't know, I put twisted more like a general suggestion when writing your own protocols, servers and handlers.

Comment: I realized how to do it. Thanks!